# Custom layout manager scroll/animation

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, carousel

**What I'm trying to do.**

Create a simple carousel with **RecyclerView**.

**Problem**

1. Initially the view is not snap to center and the view is not getting the style I intended to.(i.e, the item which is fully visible should be bigger than other, when scroll by finger it works fine)
2. When scroll programmatically the view is not getting snap effect like it does when scroll with finger.

See the attached **gif** below for example.

[image]

**Question**

1. How to have the style as intended (i.e the fully visible item is bigger) when started.
2. How to get the style when scroll to button is click. (It scrolls to correct position the only problem is not getting the style as intended and its not snap to center)

Full code here on [github](https://github.com/PuniCharana/Carousel-Demo/tree/recycler-view-carousel)

Here's the code for custom **LayoutManager**

```
open class CarouselLayoutManager(
    context: Context,
    orientation: Int,
    reverseLayout: Boolean
) : LinearLayoutManager(context, orientation, reverseLayout) {

private val mShrinkAmount = 0.15f
private val mShrinkDistance = 0.9f

override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
    scrollVerticallyBy(0, recycler, state)
    super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state)
}

override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
    val orientation = orientation
    if (orientation == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
        val scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state)

        val midpoint = width / 2f
        val d0 = 0f
        val d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint
        val s0 = 1f
        val s1 = 1f - mShrinkAmount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            val childMidpoint = (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2f
            val d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint))
            val scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0)
            child.scaleX = scale
            child.scaleY = scale
        }
        return scrolled
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
    val orientation = orientation
    if (orientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        val scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state)
        val midpoint = height / 2f
        val d0 = 0f
        val d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint
        val s0 = 1f
        val s1 = 1f - mShrinkAmount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            val childMidpoint = (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2f
            val d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint))
            val scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0)
            child.scaleX = scale
            child.scaleY = scale
        }
        return scrolled
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This occurs as your first item starts at the start position of your recycler view - this behaviour will also be the inverse at the end item - it will never snap to the centre. Create a second ViewHolder for "header" and "footer" positions (item count = data size + 2) have a width of : width = (screen width / 2) - (normal view holder max width / 2).  I have done something similar but I create a custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` before - my code works, however the logic takes a different approach, so posting that won't help, but the key is the header (start) and footer (finish) views.

Comment: That make sense that first and last item wont snap to center, however if i ignore the first and last item is there a way to start the recycler view from middle or the second position?

Comment: You could probably implement some special left/right padding on the first/last items (set dynamically based of the screen size and depth) however this could get quite ugly, as view holders get reused (i.e. these would have special behaviours even though they are same view holders), and this would probably have to be done when the view is bound the data (onBind) when you know the position.  I'm only thinking off top of my head - there are probably different way to do this, I chose one and went with it .. good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem by using this libraries/examples

1. [DiscreteScrollView](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView)
2. [android-viewpager-transformers](https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers)

**Here is the final result.**

For full code see [Carousel Demo](https://github.com/PuniCharana/Carousel-Demo)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

call `scrollVerticallyBy(0, recycler, state)` in `onLayoutCompleted()` method